# Skype chat opens full screen and I can't get off it

Tags: skype

Skype was working perfect and then all of a sudden the chat box was full screen sized. Once you click on the Skype icon from the side bar it takes you straight to the full sized chat windows (By full sized I mean the side bar, top bar, and the programs close buttons disappear)
I have uninstalled Skype and installed again but the issue is still occurring.

I looked about but couldn't find an answer, thanks for any help!

Comment: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> worked for me where just <kbd>F11</kbd> did not.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and couldn't find an answer, but have found a solution
under the Skype **Options** menu under **Chat** *deselect* **use default view**.

Apparently the default view is a full screen window with a locked window size.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts, finally could fix it with your suggestion.

Comment: ty solved my problem..

Answer (score 6):

- Open ~/.Skype/skypeusername/config.xml
- find the xml-node `ConversationsWindow` and set it to something else so it would not fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

first do the Skype Options menu under Chat deselect use default view.
Then follow this steps:

1. Close the skype.
2. go to /home/userfolder/
3. select the show hidden files or cntr+h
4. rename the ".skype" folder to ".skype_backup"
5. open the skype
6. you will see the ".skype" and ".skype_backup" folders at above location.
7. delete the ".skype" folder and rename the ".skype_backup" to ".skype"
8. Close the skype
9. again open the skype.

then the sype will be working fine..

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just to press the <kbd>F11</kbd> key in Ubuntu.

The <kbd>F11</kbd> key toggles full screen. No other keys are needed.

Comment: Worked well on 16.04. Quickest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for keyboard shortcuts, you can maximize windows by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>̣↑</kbd> and minimize by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>̣↓</kbd>.

Also, <kbd>F11</kbd> toggles the full screen mode.

Further keyboard shortcuts can be found under `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`.

Comment: Super? what key is that aha?

Comment: As in the start key in Windows.

Comment: I noticed after I sent that comment. I tried that but it never done anything. Restarted PC again and when I click on someone it still sets the chat box full screen with noway to minimize it.

Comment: Hmmm. How about Alt+Tab to cycle or Alt+F9 for minimise?

Comment: Nothing :/ Thanks for your help man, appreciated :)!

Comment: No problem mate. Why don't you check your Keyboard shorcuts from System Settings while you you're at it.

Comment: None of them where set tbh. I'm new to Ubuntu :p I have changed any ones that looked of relevance to it. Can you suggest anyones that may help? Thanks again man :)

Comment: Well, so now are you able to minimise from within Skype?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem with the "main window" of skype, go to:

1) Options -> General -> check "Start Skype minimized in the system tray"
2) Restart Skype